# Weird bug with external Monitor on Linux

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, hdmi, xorg, external-display

I own a Dell Inspiron 15 7590, with Intel i5 9300H and a Nvidia GeForce GTX 1650 with 2x8Gigs of DDR4 RAM that I bought separately from Crucial. It runs a classic Win 10 installation, on a 480Gb nvme drive bought from corsair, and I use the built-in 512Gb nvme drive from SK Hynix to run a fresh Pop! OS 21.10 install. I use the default desktop manager (gdm3).

I use an external Monitor which is an [Iiyama Prolite 27"](https://iiyama.com/fr_fr/produits/prolite-xub2792qsu-b1/) running 2560x1440p @ 60Hz via HDMi (it is indeed the recommended settings if you read the manufacturer's recommandation). Otherwise, this monitor is plugged in via DisplayPort into my Win 10 Desktop Computer and can support 2560x1440p @ 70Hz.

However, I cannot make it work with my current Pop! OS install on the Dell laptop no matter what. The problem is that the monitor indeed appears in the display preferences of Pop! OS and xrandr tells me that the screen is connected to the DP-3 port of my computer, and using 2560x1440 @ 59.95Hz as its current and preferred mode. But, the screen stays black after a frustrating "No signal", even though it seems to be detected. However, **I can switch it to 1920x1080 @ 60Hz and it works**, but it's a kinda awful experience if you'd ask me.

What I tried so far :

- installing the latest nvidia driver for linux via the graphics-driver ppa (currently running 510), with no effect (here is the `nvidia-smi` output).

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 510.47.03    Driver Version: 510.47.03    CUDA Version: 11.6     |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   41C    P3     6W /  N/A |      4MiB /  4096MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                           
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A     21362      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                  4MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

- using a custom mode with xrandr, trying to mess a bit with refresh rates and using both cvt and gtf modelines for 2560x1440 @ 60, 50, 30 Hz ; with no effect

```
xrandr --newmode [modeline]
xrandr --addmode [DisplayName] [MyCustomMode]
xrandr --output [DisplayName] --mode [MyCustomMode]
```

- using a custom mode with xrandr, this time using the 2560x1440 modeline I got from Monitor Asset Manager in Windows 10, with no effect.
- trying to switch to lightdm, but it kinda break my desktop and had no effect.
- using a different HDMI cable, with no effect.
- **Trying a different 2560x1440 monitor, which surprisingly did work** directly via plug and play without any need to tweak xrandr settings ! it's a Benq one from my roommate. I also try to use different cables, including the ones I used with my monitor and everything works perfectly with my roommate's monitor.

So right now my only guess is that the Iiyama Prolite 27" 2560x1440 monitor is not compatible with my current Pop! OS install, but to be honest I find it quite weird. Does anyone could have a lead ?

I looked through forums, bug reports and so without finding any clues as I guess this "bug" is very specific. I might have found a similar issue [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1871721) but I'm not quite sure what the solution would be.

Thanks in advance ! Sorry if there is english mistakes in this post, not my native language.

**Edit :**
I tried to use a live USB to test another distro of linux, the problem occurs with the Cinnamon ver. of Linux Mint 20.3. At this point I was thinking that it also uses Gnome and is also a Ubuntu-based distro, so this might not help me. I then tried with the KDE version of Manjaro 21.2.2, since it's an Arch based distro and a different desktop environment. Well, the problem still occurs : the monitor is recognized, but 1440p isn't working. If I switch to 1080p it works again.

Now I really think it comes from my monitor model, the Iiyama Prolite XUB2792QSU-B1. Is there anything on certain models of monitors that do work and others don't on Linux ?

**Edit 2 :**
So  I started a live USB of Manjaro 21.2.2 on my desktop computer, which is connected to my monitor in 2560x1440@60Hz via DisplayPort. **The monitor displays everything without problems, even with open-source drivers**. I'm beginning to think it might be a problem with the HDMI port of my Dell laptop. Could it be that it is not made to display higher resolutions than 1080p ? If the problem does not come from the distro nor from the drivers in use, I think it might be a hardware or firmware problem ; or it comes from the monitor's HDMI port limitations since every thing is fine when it is plugged to another monitor with the same cable. I'm kinda clueless right now to be honest.